# How to create an object type, with keys based on an objects values

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to turn an object into a dynamically created typing. But I'm struggling to get it right.

Let's say I have an object:

```
const constants = {
   filter: 'flr',
   color: 'col'
}
```

How would I be able to make a type, that would allow the following:

```
type MetaData = {
   flr: number
   col: string
}

//js
const meta: MetaData = getMeta();
const filterValue: number = meta[constants.filter];
```

Whenever one of the constant values changes, I want the type to automatically be updated as well.

I have tried to set this up by doing the following:

```
type MetaData = {
  [constants.filter]: number
  [k: constants.filter]: number
  [k: any extends constants.filter]: number
}
```

But nothing seems to work, and I can't seem to find a proper solution for this. Any hints for a working type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const constants = {
  filter: 'flr',
  color: 'col'
} as const; // very important

type Constants = typeof constants; // represents the type of the constants object
type ConstantsValues = Constants[keyof Constants] // defines values of constants object
type MetaData = {
   [K in ConstantsValues]: any // map which has all keys as values of constants object
}

// using
const meta: MetaData = {
  flr: 1,
  col: 2
}
const filterValue: number = meta[constants.filter];
```

**Explanation**

Most important is to define `constants` as [const](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), it means that we are saying this structure of the object is permanent and the inferred types should be precise to exactly that. Thanks to `const` the `typeof constants` defines exact keys and values which the object has.

Next things are two types  `Constants` and `ConstantsValues` which are just simple definitions of types from the `constants` object. They are here for readability purposes.

Last is `MetaData`. We define it as map which keys are all values of the `constants` object. I set values as `any` as you did not define the need about this.

Any change of the `constants` object will effect the need of changing every instance of `Metadata` type.

---

If the whole `Metadata` object should have one type of value, as you have shown in your example by `number`, it can be achieved by:

```
type MetaData = {
   [K in ConstantsValues]: number // here we have a number for all values
}
```

or in more polymorphic way:

```
type MetaData<V> = {
   [K in ConstantsValues]: V // here we have V for all values
}

type MetaDataStr = MetaData<string>
type MetaDataNum = MetaData<number>
```

---

Additional need was requested in the comment. The need is to be able to define types which will represent partial of the `constants` object with different type of values. Here is an example of implementing that:

```
// bigger object to have an example
const constants = {
  filter: 'flr',
  color: 'col',
  rank: 'rnk',
  size: 'sz'
} as const;

// the same two types as previous
type Constants = typeof constants;
type ConstantsValues = Constants[keyof Constants];

// create parts of values 
type PartOfConstantsA = Extract<ConstantsValues, 'flr' | 'col'>
type PartOfConstantsB = Extract<ConstantsValues, 'rnk' | 'sz'>

// create more generic type in order to pass also keys by Keys generic
type MetaData<Keys extends PropertyKey, Values> = {
  [K in Keys]: Values
}

// we combine both types by &
type FinalMetaData = MetaData<PartOfConstantsA, number> & MetaData<PartOfConstantsB, string>;

// using
const meta: FinalMetaData = {
  flr: 1, // needs to be number
  col: 2,// needs to be number
  rnk: 'a', // needs to be string
  sz: 'b' // needs to be number
}
const filterValue = meta[constants.filter];
```

Comment: Nice! How would you go about this when actually defining a sub set of constant values. So the `constants` contain 20 key/value pairs, and the type I want only needs 2 of those key value pairs. Is it possible to pick only one of the `ConstantValues` and give it a specific type?

Meaning, is it possible to map those ConstantValues to a key specific type. 
```
type MetaData = {
   [K: ConstantsValues['flr']]: number, 
   [K: ConstantsValues['col']]: string, 
}
```

Comment: phw - will try to address your comment in the answer. give me few moments

Comment: changed the answer to have this case also